# How is the rate of damping affected by frequency and harmonics?

Tags: waves

Let's say we have a standing wave whose fundamental frequency $f$ damps at a rate proportional to $e^{-\kappa t}$. How does the rate of damping for the $n$th harmonic relate to this?

I can't seem to find the answer online, but intuition tells me that the answer is $e^{-n\kappa t}$, because higher frequencies decay more rapidly. Is this correct?

---

Additionally, let's say we can change the fundamental frequency of our standing wave only by changing its length. Let's let $r=\frac{f}{f_0}$, the ratio between the new frequency and the old frequency.

Again, the Internet fails me, but I feel intuitively that it would result in a damping rate of $e^{-r\kappa t}$, and for the harmonics of this new wave, $e^{-rn\kappa t}$. As before, this is because higher frequencies should decay faster. Is this true?

Comment: There are many different physical processes that cause damping, and they don't all behave the same way. So the question is unanswerable.

Comment: It would depend on whether damping acts on speed, amplitude, or something else. You should start with modeling your specific type of damping.

Comment: @alephzero I mean in the ideal case. Obviously real-world scenarios will differ somewhat.

Comment: @safesphere I'm referring to amplitude only.